# XPath syntax to extract URL from HTMLNode using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

What is the proper **XPath** syntax to grab the value of the **href** attribute from the following *HTMLNode*:

```
<a target="_blank" class="monkeys" href="http://someurl.com" id="123">
    <span class="title">Monkeys are flying all over!</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//a[@id='123']/@href
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is `//a@href` what you're looking for?

Using HTMLAgilityPack, the method you'd use is:

```
HTMLAgilityPack.HTMLNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
```

Comment: That is invalid, you probably want `//a/@href`, which will find the `href` attribute of any number of `a` elements. I believe (as reflected in my answer) that "Darth" is looking for that specific `a` element.

Comment: i am using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.GetAttributeValue() but it does not seem to work for attributes that are defined using single quotes  like this: <a href='adomain.com/page'>link</a>. Any ideas?